# Почему не работает сортировка слиянием?

Tags: c++

Написал вот такой алгортим сортировки слиянием, потратил уже несколько часов, не могу понять, почему он не хочет работать. Помогите доработать, чтобы код справлялся со своей задачей.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void merge2(vector <int>& a, int n, vector <int>& b,
    int m, vector <int>& c)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m)
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            c[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else {
            c[k++] = b[j++];
        }
    while (i < n) {
        c[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < m) {
        c[k++] = b[j++];
    }
}

void merge(int *a,int left,int right,int mid )
{
    int i = left, j = mid + 1;
    //int* tmp = new int[right - left + 1];
    vector <int> tmp(right - left + 1);
    int k = 0;
    while (i <= mid && j <=right)
        if (a[i] < a[j]) {
            tmp[k++] = a[i++];;
        }
        else {
            tmp[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    while (i <= mid) {
        tmp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j <= right) {
        tmp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        a[i] = tmp[i - left];
    }
}

void mergesort(int *a,int left,int right) {
    int mid;
    if (left < right) {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        //делим массив на две части
        mergesort(a, left,mid);
        mergesort(a, mid, right);
        //производим слиянием двух отсортированных массивов
        merge(a, left, right, mid);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    mergesort(a, 0,n-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  mergesort(a, left, mid);
  mergesort(a, mid+1, right);
```

Думаю, пояснений не требуется